# WordPress 3.8 keeps asking me to upgrade to 3.8

Tags: upgrade, localization, git

It began with version `3.7.1`:

> You are using WordPress 3.7.1. Update to 3.7.1

I've installed and usually update WP with git from `https://github.com/wordpress/wordpress`:

```
cd wordpress
git fetch --tags
git checkout 3.8
```

Then I usually download localized version (`ru_RU`) and copy over updated language files (`wp-content/languages/`).

Everything was smooth until 3.7.1 and it looks like I'm [not](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/keeps-asking-me-to-upgrade-to-371) the only one encountering this issue.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just downloading the zip from wp.org?

Comment: Yep, tried simple update by hitting «Update Now» button @ `/wp-admin/update-core.php`. It updates and redirects me to awesome `/wp-admin/about.php` page but «Update Nag» still there.

Comment: What's the version number in wp-includes/version.php?

Comment: `$wp_version = '3.8';` Checked that out too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you tried everything in the thread you linked? specifically, deleting everything in options table prefixed with `_transient`.

Comment: Have you tried: - backing up your database - deactivating all plugins. - switching to the WordPress default theme. - re-running the upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the update now button, use a full on download of the core WP - http://wordpress.org/download/ - and then make sure you flush any cache you've got running. Do you have memcached or APC or xcache? Purge that. Plugins ditto.

I saw that on one of my sites where my server's object cache hung on to things. I went and checked the readme.html and verified I WAS on the right version, so I knew it had to be cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say flush server cache, browser cache then log out of WP. log back in after you flush everything. Should be fine. It's a cache issue most likely.